# Flatten vector of classes which contain vectors of structs

Tags: c++, c++20, stl-algorithm, std-ranges

I have a vector of a class `Planters` which contain vectors of `Plant`s. My goal is to return a vector of plants containing the plants from planter 1, followed by plants from planter 2, etc.
example: `planter{{1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4,5}}` should lead to `{1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5}`. note that the numbers represent plant objects. I'm trying to use `join_view` to flatten it but I am getting the error

```
error: class template argument deduction failed:
   18 |         plants = std::ranges::join_view(planterView);
      |                                                    ^
/home/parallels/CMPT373/se-basic-cpp-template/lib/solutions/task05.cpp:18:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘join_view(std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<ex4::Planter> >&)’
```

I have tried the following :

```
for (auto it : planters){
  plants.insert(plants.end(), it.getPlants().begin(), it.getPlants().end());
}
```

This works however I am only allowed to use one loop (excluding loops inside STL function calls) and can only allocate memory once. The above approach allocates memory multiple times. How do I approach this?

my code:

```
std::vector<Plant> task05(std::vector<Planter> planters){
    std::vector<Plant> plants;
    auto planterView = std::views::all(planters);
    std::views::transform(planterView, [](Planter planter){ return planter.getPlants();});
    plants = ranges::views::all(std::ranges::join_view(planterView));
    return plants;
}
```

Class:

```
struct Plant {
  int plantiness = 0;

  Plant(int plantiness)
    : plantiness{plantiness}
      { }

  bool
  operator==(const Plant& other) const noexcept {
    return plantiness == other.plantiness;
  }
};


class Planter {
public:
  Planter(std::initializer_list<Plant> plants)
    : plants{plants}
      { }

  const std::vector<Plant>&
  getPlants() const noexcept {
    return plants;
  }

private:
  std::vector<Plant> plants;
};
```

Comment: Updated with the error message @JaMiT

Comment: `auto planterView = std::views::transform(std::views::all(planters), [](Planter planter){ return planter.getPlants();});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::vector<Plant> task05(std::vector<Planter> planters)
{
    auto plants = planters
        | std::views::transform([](Planter const& planter) -> decltype(auto) { return planter.getPlants();})
        | std::views::join
        | std::views::common
        ;
    return std::vector<Plant>(plants.begin(), plants.end());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T75anE15c

Firstly you go wrong here

```
auto planterView = std::views::all(planters);
std::views::transform(planterView, [](Planter planter){ return planter.getPlants();});
```

`std::transform` is inplace but `views::transform` is not and returns a view which you ignore, but this needs to be passed into `join_view`.

Secondly, begin and end return different types, but the constructor of `std::vector` needs these to have the same type, so you have to use `views::common` to achieve this.

Thirdly, the deduced return type of the lamdba doesn't propagate the `const&`-ness of `getPlants` resulting in a copy. You have declare the return type as `decltype(auto)`.

---

Also, you don't need to call `views::all`. It will be automatically called when calling `transform` and you should use the `join` adapter rather than the `join_view` type.

Also, ranges are very ergonomic when used in a pipeline so just writing one expression spanning multiple lines is best practice.

Also, there's not much point wrapping `int` and `std::vector<int>` in structs. It's easy just to use `std::tuple`, `std::array`, `std::variant`, `std::optional` and never actually write your own types.

Comment: `views::transform(&Planter::getPlants)` is a lot better btw: it avoids the mistake of accidentally taking the object by value in the lambda, but also in this case `getPlants` returns a reference so you're accidentally copying it there too. Plus, _because_ you're now returning a value, the resulting `join` ends up being a non-common, input range - where if the transform returned a reference, it'd be a common, bidirectional range.

Comment: "accidentally copying it there too" [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74084224/11998382)