# Difference between lambda and member function pointer

Tags: c++, std-ranges

In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078452/11998382), Barry pointed out that it's better to call `views::transform(&Planter::getPlants)` because `views::transform([](Planter const& planter){...` accidentally copies.

```cpp
#if 1
    auto plants = planters
        | std::views::transform([](Planter const& planter){ return planter.getPlants();})
        | std::views::join
        | std::views::common
        ;
// Plant copy constructor
// Plant copy constructor
// Plant copy constructor
// Plant copy constructor
// Plant copy constructor
#else
    auto plants = planters
        | std::views::transform(&Planter::getPlants)
        | std::views::join
        ;
#endif
// Plant copy constructor
// Plant copy constructor
```

Here `Plant` is a wrapper around `int` and `Planter` is a wrapper around `std::vector<int>`.

https://godbolt.org/z/dr7PM5Tvd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I actually know this one. The deduced return type of the lambda actually decays the const ref qualifiers of `getPlants`.

You can fix this by declaring the return type of the lambda to be `decltype(auto)`

```cpp
views::transform([](Planter const& planter) -> decltype(auto){...});
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ocK5PG1z1

Comment: Then how it is possible to be a copy?

Comment: @UserUsing you'll have to clarify

Comment: Good one, I lost count of how many times I've made this mistake.

Comment: *views::transform([](Planter const& planter){... accidentally copies.* I am wondering how; because what we returning in the lambda is a ref wrapper to the vector of "Plant"/ int. This is a const ref, so no copy, right?

Comment: @UserUsing no the const ref decays for the lambda's deduced return type unless you have `-> decltype(auto)`.

Comment: That means const ref decays to just copy unless we say decltype (auto), right?

Comment: @UserUsing Yes, the return type of `getPlants` is `Planter const&` but without `decltype(auto)` the return type of the lambda is just `Planter`